# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError bitmap create?

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I just got this stack trace from the marketplace error reporting and have no idea where to being to track the problem down, any help appreciated.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:349)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:463)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:326)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:440)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.initialize(IconMenuItemView.java:109)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.createItemView(MenuItemImpl.java:594)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getItemView(MenuItemImpl.java:577)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.updateChildren(IconMenuView.java:351)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.initialize(IconMenuView.java:333)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder$MenuType.getMenuView(MenuBuilder.java:199)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.getMenuView(MenuBuilder.java:323)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.initializePanelContent(PhoneWindow.java:858)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.openPanel(PhoneWindow.java:435)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUpPanel(PhoneWindow.java:621)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUp(PhoneWindow.java:1339)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1668)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchKeyEvent(TabHost.java:278)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1687)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1120)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2073)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1663)
at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2560)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2535)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1867)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same error on an application I've developed for Android 2.1 and Android 2.2 but run on Android 4.0.1 ICS. The same app would run on Android 2.1 but cause a crash with the above error on ICS. If you're drawing something relatively big to the size of the screen, consider checking from that place.